# How to use Katalon with AngularJS Ui-select?

Tags: angularjs, katalon-studio, ui-select

I'm having a form with at least 3 `<ui-select></ui-select>` tags, when i run Katalon automated test, i cannot use Web UI keyword `Select Options by value` to set the value for the element. Is there any way to handle this problem? Hope to see your experiences...

*HTML:

```
<ui-select theme="select2" ng-model="dataPalete.fid" ng-required="true">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="..."><% $select.selected.name %></ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="fruits.id as fruit in fruit_select | filter: $select.search">
      <span ng-bind="fruit.name"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

```
<script>
   app.controller('fruitController', function($scope){
      $scope.fruit_select = [
         {id: 'APPL', name: 'Apple'},
         {id: 'BANN', name: 'Banana'},
         {id: 'ORGA', name: 'Orange'} 
      ];
   });
</script>
```

*Katalon script:

```
import static com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory.findCheckpoint
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory.findTestCase
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory.findTestData
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.Checkpoint as Checkpoint
import com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords as CucumberKW
import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords as Mobile
import com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling as FailureHandling
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCase as TestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestData as TestData
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject as TestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords as WS
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI
import internal.GlobalVariable as GlobalVariable
...
CustomKeywords.'com.katalon.plugin.keyword.angularjs.DropdownKeywords.selectOptionByName'(findTestObject('Fruit/dropdown_selectfruit'),'Apple')
```

Answer (score 0):

Katalon offers a lot of plugins. https://store.katalon.com

Did you look at this one? https://store.katalon.com/product/23/AngularJS-Dropdown-Keywords

He seems to be responding to your request.

Comment: I think it won't take any affect to ui-select of AngularJS

Comment: The description of the keyword : "The custom keywords list below are used to support for scripting the Dropdown element(*-select) in AngularJS application". Do you have read documentation ?

Comment: I've read and tried in my project, it can dropdown but cannot set select option by name...

Comment: Can you put some code on your question ? Because without context it is not easy to help you.

Comment: Script in Katalon